# how using foreach in ajax codeigniter

Tags: arrays, ajax, codeigniter

Dear Expert need help how to add foreach between variable tbaris :

```
function show_infouser(Kode)
   { save_method = 'update';
       $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
       $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
       $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
       $.ajax({url : "<?php echo site_url('infouser/ajax_user')?>/" + Kode,
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "JSON",
       success: function(data){
         if (data == null)
         { showConfirmButton: false }); }
         else {
// want to show foreach in here
           var tbaris = '<tr><td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+data.No+'</center></td>';
           tbaris += '<td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+data.Name+'</center></td>';
           tbaris += '<td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+data.Job+'</center></td>';
           tbaris += '<td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+data.Status+'</center></td>';
           $('#tableuser tbody').html(tbaris);
           $('#modal_form1').modal('show');
           $('.modal-title').text('SHOW ROOM');}},
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
               {
                   alert('Error get data from ajax' + errorThrown);
                   alert('Error get data from ajax' + textStatus);
                   alert('Error get data from ajax' + jqXHR);
               }
           });
       }
```

Comment: also post your controller....code.How you send data back from server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below using `$.each()`...

```
 function show_infouser(Kode)
       { 
           save_method = 'update';
           $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
           $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
           $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

           $.ajax({
           url : "<?php echo base_url('infouser/ajax_user');?>/" + Kode,
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "JSON",
           success: function(response){
             if (response == null)
             { showConfirmButton: false } 
             else {
// want to show foreach in here
            var tbaris ='';
            $.each(response,function(index) {
            tbaris += '<tr><td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+response[index].No+'</center></td>';
           tbaris += '<td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+response[index].Name+'</center></td>';
           tbaris += '<td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+response[index].Job+'</center></td>';
           tbaris += '<td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+response[index].Status+'</center></td>';
           }
           $('#tableuser tbody').html(tbaris);
           $('#modal_form1').modal('show');
           $('.modal-title').text('SHOW ROOM');
             }
         },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
               {
                   alert('Error get data from ajax' + errorThrown);
                   alert('Error get data from ajax' + textStatus);
                   alert('Error get data from ajax' + jqXHR);
               }
           });
       }
```

Comment: hi Hikmat Sijapati,
first i have error on if(data == null) i change into if(response==null)
and i get new error 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data[Learn More]

Comment: please post your controller's code also it will be easy.

Comment: also try once without using `JSON.parse();`..some errors related to parenthesis are removed.

Comment: theres no problem with my controller before i add code var data = JSON.parse(response); data just show first line so i think the problem in foreach cause ajax not support i agree form ur code using JSON.parse but still error

Comment: if i remove JSON.parse(); the data just display first row of data
inside data have 4 rows

Comment: this my controller
public function ajax_detail($Kode)
 {
  $data = $this->infouser->get_by_id1($Kode);
  echo json_encode($data);      
 }

Comment: you have to use `$.each`.ok m going to edit..wait a moment.

Comment: Hi Hikmat, 
all row and column show 
undefined undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined undefined

Comment: `console.log(response);` and post your output please.

Comment: where i have to put console.log(response); ?
before var tbaris =''; or after tbaris += '<td style="width:3px; font-size:11px;"><center>'+response[index].Status+'</center></td>';
           }

Comment: above the if statement inside success function.

Comment: ill try to remove typing index in 
+response[index].No+
+response[index].nama+
with
+response.No+
+response.nama+
data show but display looping with the same data

Comment: post your response..i have check whether it is array or object.

Comment: thanks Hikmat at last i found the problems not in my controller but in my model where return my code return $query->row(); i have change into $query->result(); and its work

Comment: yes in codeigniter `row()` gives first row of record only.for fetching all results you have to use `result()`.

Comment: and another important thing is `result()` always outputs in object format.for array format you have to use `result_array()`.

Comment: @Wahyu Artadianto happy programming ahead ..if you think answer is useful accept it and vote up thank you.